# dynamic route not displaying the component in react and react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using React and `react-router`. When I try to go to this route `<Route path="/blogs/:id" element={<Blog/>} />` from the `Blogs`  page the whole content of the `Blog` page content is blank and I have a lot of errors.

[image]
[image]

App.jsx

```
import Footer from "./components/Footer"
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar"
import Blogs from "./pages/Blogs"
import Cart from "./pages/Cart"
import Home from "./pages/Home"
import Shop from "./pages/Shop"
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css'
import Blog from "./pages/Blog"

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/shop" element={<Shop />} />
        <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
        <Route path="/blogs" element={<Blogs />} />
        <Route path="/blogs/:id" element={<Blog/>} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Blogs.jsx

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import PageTitle from "../components/PageTitle"
import Data from '../data/Data.json'

const Blogs = () => {
  return (
    <section>
      <PageTitle title={'Blogs'} />

      <div className="container my-5">
        <div className="row">
          {Data.blogs.map((blog, i) => {
            const { id, title, author, image, publishedDate, views } = blog
            const truncatedTitle = title.length > 60 ? title.substring(0, 60) + '...' : title;
            return (
              <Link to={`/blogs/${id}`} key={i} className="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 my-3" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                <div>
                  <div className="post-entry">
                    <div className="post-thumbnail">
                      <img src={image} alt="Image" className="img-fluid" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="post-content-entry">
                      <h6 className="my-2">{truncatedTitle}</h6>
                      <div className="meta">
                        <div>by {author}</div>
                        <div>on {publishedDate}</div>
                        <div><i className="fa-solid fa-eye ms-5"></i> {views}</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Link>
            )
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Blogs
```

Blog.jsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"
import Data from '../data/Data.json'

const Blog = () => {
  const { id } = useParams()
  const [blog, setBlog] = useState(null);
  const { title, author, image, content, publishedDate, views } = blog
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const singleBlog = Data.blogs.find(item => item.id === parseInt(id))

    if (singleBlog) {
      setBlog(singleBlog)
    }
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <section>
      <div className="container pt-5">
        {blog ? (
          <div className="blog">
            <img src={image} height={'300px'}/>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            <div>
              <span>by {author}</span>
              <span className="mx-5">on {publishedDate}</span>
              <span><i className="fa-solid fa-eye ms-5"></i> {views}</span>
            </div>
            <p>{content}</p>
          </div>
        ) : 'not found blog'}
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Blog
```

Comment: Consider adding a minimal reproductive example inside of a code sandbox. Also, do not post error logs as an image.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `blog` state is initially `null`, not an `object` so `title` and the other properties can not be destructed from the `blog` state.

You can try to resolve it this way:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"
import Data from '../data/Data.json'
const Blog = () => {
  const {id} = useParams()
  const [blog, setBlog] = useState(null);
        
  useEffect(() => {
    const singleBlog = Data.blogs.find(item => item.id === parseInt(id))

    if(singleBlog){
      setBlog(singleBlog)
    }
  }, []);
  
  if (blog === null) return <h1>Loading... Please Wait (add custom loading here)</h1>
  if (blog === undefined) return <h1>Blog not found (add custom 404 page here)</h1>
  const { title, author, image, content, publishedDate , views} = blog
  
  return (
    <section>
      <div className="container pt-5">
        {
          blog ? (
            <div className="blog">
              <img src={image} height={'300px'}/>
              <h2>{title}</h2>
              <div>
                <span>by {author}</span>
                <span className="mx-5">on {publishedDate}</span>
                <span><i className="fa-solid fa-eye ms-5"></i> {views}</span>
              </div>
              <p>{content}</p>
            </div>
          ) : 'not found blog'
        }
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Blog
```

This way, you won't try to obtain `blog.title` until `blog` is set to an object. There are two cases I added here, I am going to try to walk you through the process here:

- 1. User opens a blog, state is equal to `null`
- 2. `useEffect` runs but that is running in async mode.
- 3. UI will render loading component until state switches from `null` to `blog` | `undefined`
- 4. A: Blog is found, state is set with the blog, data is obtained and the blog rendered.
- 4. B: Blog is NOT found, state is set to `undefined`, UI renders 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

the initial `blog` state value is `null`, and immediately after declaring the `blog` state you attempt to destructure properties from this null value.

```js
const [blog, setBlog] = useState(null);
const { title, author, image, content, publishedDate, views } = blog;
```

You obviously can't do this.

## Solution

The UI should wait until `blog` is a defined object prior to attempting to destructure properties from it. It's also a bit of a React anti-pattern to store derived "state" into React state. The current blog value is easily computed from the `id` route path parameter and the imported JSON data.

Additional things to keep in mind:

- `Array.prototype.find` returns `undefined` if no matching element is found.
- Route path params are ***always*** strings, so it's likely safer to use a type-safe string comparison than it is to convert the params to number types.

Example solution:

```js
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"
import data from "../data/Data.json";

const Blog = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const blog = data.blogs.find(item => String(item.id) === id);

  if (!blog) {
    return <div>not found blog</div>;
  }

  // Safe to access blog properties now
  const { title, author, image, content, publishedDate, views } = blog;
  
  return (
    <section>
      <div className="container pt-5">
        <div className="blog">
          <img src={image} height="300px" />
          <h2>{title}</h2>
          <div>
            <span>by {author}</span>
            <span className="mx-5">on {publishedDate}</span>
            <span>
              <i className="fa-solid fa-eye ms-5" /> {views}
            </span>
          </div>
          <p>{content}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Blog;
```